# KendoUI - disable certain nodes when selecting

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have 2 Kendo Treeview; 1 without checkbox, another 1 is with checkboxes [like example here](https://dojo.telerik.com/eMUyUguL).
Lets say I want to disable certain nodes on the second treeview, treeview with the checkboxes when I select a certain nodes on the first one (eg. I want to disable nodes that are not furniture when I select furniture). The process is kinda the same like [example here](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/api) but without the button, only from selecting the node on the first treeview. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TreeList has an event called [`select`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview/events/select) which can handle that behaviour for you:

```
select: function(e) { 
    let tv = $("#treeview-right").data("kendoTreeView"), // Gets the 2dn treeview reference
        text = e.sender.dataItem(e.node).text; // Gets the 1st treeview selected text

    // Iterates over the 2nd treeview items
    tv.items().toArray().forEach(item => {
        let dataItem = tv.dataItem(item), // Get the item related dataItem
            disabled = (dataItem.type !== text); // Figures out if the current item is of selected type

        // Gets the current item's checkbox
        $(item).find('input[type="checkbox"]')
            .prop('checked', false) // Uncheck it by default
            .prop('disabled', disabled); // Disable/enable based on above condition
    });
}
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/eMUyUguL/6)

Alternative: You can do like below to filter the second TreeView:

```
select: function(e) { 
    let tv = $("#treeview-right").data("kendoTreeView"),
        text = e.sender.dataItem(e.node).text;

    tv.dataSource.filter({ field: "type", operator: "eq", value: text });
}
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/eMUyUguL/5)

Comment: Exactly what i need. Thanks!